# How do I tell browser, "Don't load any external scripts from example.com"

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-addons, proxy

I'm using the Firefox add-on FoxyProxy to route all external scripts from example.com to staging.example.com.

But now I'd like to see what the page looks like when those scripts are completely disabled.

What's the easiest way (preferrably using FoxyProxy) to be able to toggle between the two: where the scripts are either proxied or not loaded/executed at all?

Answer (score 2):

[NoScript](http://noscript.net/) can block scripts per domain.